# updating NSLayoutConstraint Programmatically Swift 4 in scrollViewDidScroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I want to update the constraints of a tableView cell's favoritesImageView's top constraint's constant in my viewController's scrollViewDidScroll method.

Below is the func in my custom tableViewCell

```
private func setupFavoritesImageView() {
    addSubview(favoritesImageView)
    favoritesImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageTopConstraint = favoritesImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:cellContentView.topAnchor)
    addConstraint(imageTopConstraint)

    imageHeightConstraint = favoritesImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellContentView.heightAnchor)
    addConstraint(imageHeightConstraint)

    [favoritesImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellContentView.centerXAnchor),
    favoritesImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellContentView.widthAnchor)]
        .forEach{$0.isActive = true}
}
```

However, when I set the constants in scrollViewDidScroll, it's detecting that my constraints are changing in the console but it looks completely different than from using the same formula but using a @IBOutlet constraint.

ViewController

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let tableView = favoritesView.tableView
    let offSetY = tableView.contentOffset.y
    for cell in tableView.visibleCells as! [FavoriteImagesTableViewCell] {
        cell.imageTopConstraint.constant = parallaxOffset(newOffsetY: offSetY, cell: cell)
        cell.setNeedsLayout()
    }
}
```

Im trying to make a parallax tableView and update the constant of the constraint programmatically. I've found that the same code used on a @IBOutlet works fine. Im having trouble implementing it in code.

*EDIT- All the constraints are activated

image link \/

[gray is cell, black is imageView background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVawj.jpg)

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try adding a `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` after the `cell.setNeedsLayout()`.

Comment: i've tried and it still pretty much looks like the image i've posted

Comment: It was just a thought.  It's getting a bit late and I took the dog on a long walk earlier so I'm quite tired.  If it hasn't been answered I will try to knock up a test app later.

Comment: yea np, this has me bugged for the past 3 days, just trying to figure out why it works using IBOutlet vs programmatic constraints.

Comment: So the images should move down the cell until they get to the bottom as the table is scrolled making them appear to stay in place (until the cell scrolls off the screen)

Comment: Possibly dumb question, sorry, I don't use scroll views. But like `viewDidLayoutSubviews` has a complimentary `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, is there a `scrollViewWillScroll`? If so, have you tried that?

Comment: @dfd no there isn't a scrollViewWillScroll.

Comment: Can you show the code for parallaxOffset so I can put it in my test project.

Comment: let parallaxOffsetSpeed: CGFloat = 40
    let cellHeight: CGFloat = 250
    var parallaxImageHeight: CGFloat {
        let maxOffset = sqrt(pow(cellHeight, 2) + 4 * parallaxOffsetSpeed * favoritesView.tableView.frame.height ) - cellHeight / 2
        return maxOffset + self.cellHeight
    }

Comment: func parallaxOffset(newOffsetY: CGFloat, cell: UITableViewCell) -> CGFloat {
        return (newOffsetY - cell.bounds.origin.y) / parallaxImageHeight * parallaxOffsetSpeed
    }

Comment: also in your cellForRowAt put these two lines
    cell.imageHeightConstraint.constant = self.parallaxImageHeight
        cell.imageTopConstraint.constant =  parallaxOffset(newOffsetY: tableView.contentOffset.y, cell: cell)

Comment: see my edit ......

Answer (score 0):

It may be a thought call that code that creates the imageView from **layoutSubviews** of the cell Only once , as that method gets called again every time you change the top constraint in **scrollViewDidScroll** , so constraints is being added again so,conflicts happen and you see that weird results

like this

[image]

Here is a demo with programmatically constraints

[ParalloxCell](https://github.com/ShKhan9/ParalloxCell)

Comment: they are activated in the setupAllViews func

Comment: you constraint isn't updated when created in code but works as IBOutlet ???

Comment: it is being updated in scrollViewDidScroll. The image is also bleeding out from the cell.

Comment: yes i want the imageview to move down as im scrolling up, how do i also prevent the imageview from bleeding out from the cell

Comment: cell.imageTopConstraint.constant = parallaxOffset(-1*newOffsetY: offSetY, cell: cell)

Comment: make the offset negative

Comment: the problem doesnt reside in the calculation, the same numbers i've used worked on if the constraints were @IBOutlet

Comment: i've added a picture if it helps to see my problem